# vlc h264 http-stream to ogg raspivid

Tags: stream, raspberry-pi, vlc, ogg, transcode

I'm trying to take a video with a camera module on the raspberry pi and stream it over http in ogg format. The standard of raspivid is h264.

What's working is to stream it in h264, but most browser with HTML5 do not support this.

```
raspivid -o - -t 9999999 -w 800 -h 600 --hflip | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8082}' :demux=h264
```

What's not working is to transcode it.

```
raspivid -o - -t 9999999 -w 800 -h 600 --hflip | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=:8082}'
```

It always tells me:

```
Buffering: 0%
```

Why is it? I'd appreciate help!

Comment: Whats the output of this? Maybe you can create a Gist or Pastebin.